# Visual Studio 2010: Automatically detect if a keyword is a pointer and write ->

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I've been using QtCreator lately and decided to try out Visual Studio 2010 (Ultimate). I noticed in QtCreator that when I write "this" and then click period, QtCreator will automatically insert a "->" because it knows "this" is a pointer. If a keyword is not a pointer, it will simply add a period (like normal).

Is this functionality possible in Visual Studio 2010 (Ultimate)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not built in to any versions of Visual Studio. You can get it if you use Visual Assist X from [Whole Tomato Software](http://www.wholetomato.com).  I do not work for them, I'm just a satisfied customer.